# SQL Group By and Lag function not giving correct output

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper, lag, partition

I have the following output:

```
 last_login                 | id  | type   | w_id
    11/9/2016  10:59:13 PM  | 123 | Thing1 | W1
    11/9/2016  10:59:15 PM  | 123 | Thing1 | W1
    11/9/2016  10:59:15 PM  | 123 | Thing1 | W3
    11/10/2016  10:59:13 PM | 123 | Thing2 | W2
    11/11/2016  10:59:13 PM | 123 | Thing1 | W1
    11/12/2016  10:59:13 PM | 123 | Thing1 | W1
    11/12/2016  10:59:13 PM | 345 | Thing1 | W4
    11/13/2016  10:59:13 PM | 345 | Thing1 | W1
    11/14/2016  10:59:13 PM | 345 | Thing2 | W2
    11/15/2016  10:59:13 PM | 345 | Thing2 | W5
    11/16/2016  10:59:13 PM | 345 | Thing1 | W1
    11/16/2016  10:59:13 PM | 345 | Thing1 | W1
    11/17/2016  10:59:13 PM | 345 | Thing1 | W4
    11/17/2016  10:59:13 PM | 345 | Thing1 | W4
```

for the below query:

```
select sa.last_login, ad.ID, sa.type, w_id,
from table1 dcc
join table2 AD
on AD.ID=DCC.id

JOIN table3 sa
ON AD.ID=sa.id
join table4 sc
on dcc.id=sc.id
where sic3=‘Something’
order by dcc.id, sa.last_login
```

I want an output of something like this:

```
last_login              | id | old_type | type | old_w_id | w_id
11/11/2016  10:59:13 PM | 123 | Thing2  | Thing1 | W2     | W1
11/17/2016  10:59:13 PM | 345 | Thing1  | Thing1 | W1     | W4
```

I'm trying to do it in the following way:

```
select

t.last_login, t.id, t.old_type, t.type , t.old_w_id, t.w_id

from

(select sa.last_login, ad.id, sa.type, 
lag(sa.type, 1) over (partition by ad.id order by sa.last_login) as old_type, w_id,
lag(w_id, 1) over (partition by ad.ID order by sa.last_login) as old_w_id from table1 dcc

join table2 AD
on ad.id=DCC.id 

JOIN table3 sa
ON AD.ID=sa.id

join table4 sc
on dcc.id=sc.id

where sc.si=’Something’
order by dcc.id, sa.last_login) t

where t.old_type like ’THING1’ and t.type like ‘THING2’

group by t.id, t.id, t.old_type, t.type, t.w_id, t.old_w_id
```

But I'm getting an output of something like this:

```
last_login              | id | old_type | type | old_w_id | w_id
11/11/2016  10:59:13 PM | 123 | Thing1  | Thing2 | W1     | W2
```

How do I get the desired output and why is my query (lag function) not working correctly?

Comment: What does `group by` have to do with this query?

Comment: It is a huge table with multiple entries per id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Edited the table output and required output in my question to get a better idea

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this.  Just use `lag()`:

```
select sa.last_login, ad.ID, sa.type, w_id,
       lag(sa.type) over (partition by ad.id order by sa.last_login) as prev_type,
       lag(sa.w_id) over (partition by ad.id order by sa.last_login) as prev_w_id
from table1 dcc join
     table2 AD
     on AD.ID = DCC.id join
     table3 sa
     on AD.ID = sa.id join
     table4 sc
     on dcc.id = sc.id
where sic3 = 'Something'
order by dcc.id, sa.last_login
```

If you just want the last row, you can use `fetch first 1 row only` or sometihng like:

```
select *
from (select sa.last_login, ad.ID, sa.type, w_id,
             lag(sa.type) over (partition by ad.id order by sa.last_login) as prev_type,
             lag(sa.w_id) over (partition by ad.id order by sa.last_login) as prev_w_id,
             row_number() over (partition by ad.id order by sa.last_login desc) as seqnum
      from table1 dcc join
           table2 AD
           on AD.ID = DCC.id join
           table3 sa
           on AD.ID = sa.id join
           table4 sc
           on dcc.id = sc.id
      where sic3 = 'Something'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by id, last_login;
```

Comment: No, I don't need just the last row because as shown in my example above (for id 123) the last two rows are Thing1, Thing1 & W1, W1, however I want Thing1, Thing2 & W1, W2. I want whenever the last time there was a change in either type or w_id.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lag on the fields you want to check (TYPE and W_ID), you can just wrap that in another select statement with a where clause that gets rid of the rows where the last one equaled the current one. For example:

**EDIT** My first answer included all rows where it just changed, all I did was take that code and wrap it to grab the highest changes partitioned by the ID.

```
create table Testing
(
    last_login date,
    id number,
    type varchar2(50),
    w_id varchar2(2)
);

insert into Testing values(to_date('11/09/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),123,'Thing1','W1');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/09/2016 10:59:15 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),123,'Thing1','W1');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/09/2016 10:59:15 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),123,'Thing1','W3');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/10/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),123,'Thing2','W2');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/11/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),123,'Thing1','W1');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/12/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),123,'Thing1','W1');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/12/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),345,'Thing1','W4');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/13/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),345,'Thing1','W1');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/14/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),345,'Thing2','W2');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/15/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),345,'Thing2','W5');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/16/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),345,'Thing1','W1');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/16/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),345,'Thing1','W1');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/17/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),345,'Thing1','W4');
insert into Testing values(to_date('11/17/2016 10:59:13 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),345,'Thing1','W4');

select LAST_LOGIN, ID, TYPE, W_ID, TypeLag, W_IDLag
from(
select LAST_LOGIN, ID, TYPE, W_ID, TypeLag, W_IDLag,
       rank() over(partition by id order by last_login desc) RankOrder
from(
select Testing.*,
       lag(TYPE,1) over(partition by ID order by last_login) TypeLag,
       lag(W_ID,1) over(partition by ID order by last_login) W_IDLag
from Testing)
where (nvl(TypeLag,'X') <> TYPE
   or nvl(W_IDLag,'X') <> W_ID)
)
where RankOrder = 1
```

Output is:

```
LAST_LOGIN  ID      TYPE    W_ID    TYPELAG     W_IDLAG
11-NOV-16   123     Thing1  W1      Thing2      W2
17-NOV-16   345     Thing1  W4      Thing1      W1
```

Comment: This does not give the expected output for id 345

Comment: This gives all rows where a change just happened. Reading over your question again, do you just want 1 row per ID?

Comment: Yes, I have shown the expected output in my question